# How to post data from javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php

I try to post single data to php page using javascript but can't get it right..
here's the code i tried:

try.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var data = 1;
$.post( "data.php", { test_data: data});
});
```

data.php:

```
<?php
$test_data = $_POST[test_data];
echo $test_data
?>
```

when I access file data.php it says  "Use of undefined constant test_data" and "Undefined index: test_data"..why is that??
can someone tell me what is wrong in the code please??

Comment: I don't know about the undefined constant error, but use `$_POST['test_data'];` instead of `$_POST[test_data];`. And, if you access try.php directly using your browser, the index is of course undefined as you didn't post any data to the script.

Comment: Post some more code of both files. I hope you have included the jQuery library in your file. Also check if the page contains any JavaScript errors using your browser's developer tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You're posting to the wrong file. Why post to `try.php` if your server-side file is `data.php`
2. `test_data` in `$_POST[]` should be a string, not a constant. use `$_POST['test_data']`.
3. You will still see an error because when you directly access `data.php` you don't post anything, so `$_POST[]` is actually empty.

Comment: sorry my bad, wrong typo..if I cannot directly access data.php so how to know if the value I wanna post to data.php is correct or not??

Comment: You can either get the response from the page (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) , or use a chrome extension like Postman, so you can manually create the `POST` data. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

This isn't valid PHP:

```
$test_data = $_POST[test_data];
```

As the error indicates, `test_data` isn't a known constant.  You need to use a string literal:

```
$test_data = $_POST["test_data"];
```

Comment: Sorry my bad..wrong typo...I already try $test_data = $_POST["test_data"]; and $test_data = $_POST['test_data']; but it says undefined index

Comment: @reza: Well, according to your code you're posting the value to `try.php` but the code is on `data.php`.  You need to post the value to the page which has the code, or put the code on the page which receives the posted value.  Or perhaps include one in the other.  Either way, the PHP code in question needs to be executed when the value is posted.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST[test_data];` != `$_POST['test_data']`

When you do `$_POST[test_data]`, you're checking if $_POST (an array) has the key `test_data`. But global variables (`$_POST`, `$_GET`, `$_SERVER`) never have a constant as selector. Check for a string.

Comment: sorry my bad, wrong typo...I already try $test_data = $_POST["test_data"]; and $test_data = $_POST['test_data']; but it keep says undefined index